# JSON module is probably installed but json_encode() doesn't exist

Tags: php, json, apache, ubuntu

I've installed LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04 and then php5-json module. It seems to be installed because it's situated on list of modules on phpinfo() page. [image: phpinfo()]

But `function_exists("json_encode")` returns `false`

UPDATE:

I solved this problem by editing file which path is marked below:
[image]

Comment: You just edited it? So a random edit will solve it ;)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ideas coming to my mind :

- Restart your server after the module installation ?
- Check your php.ini and look for a line which looks like :

  extension=json.so

Comment: I've added extension=json.so to both cgi/php.ini and cli/php.ini. Now I can run 'composer install' (before it throws error about json_encode) but json_encode() on web page still doesn't work.

Comment: I've just updated my post with explanation how I've solved my problem.